# Why do images in Grid Layout in a List view spans to all columns in IOS on .Net MAUI?

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell

I have Grid Layout in a list view, which has 2 columns and 2 rows, it displays an image and some text on right of image.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Comm_News}" Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemTapped="Community_ItemTapped"                   
                  RowHeight="120"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PageBack}"
                  x:Name="news_list"
                  Margin="15,0,15,15" SeparatorColor="LightGray"
                  >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CommunityStory">
            <ViewCell >
                <Grid Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White" ColumnSpacing="10" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions  >
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".30*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".70*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Title}"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="Read more"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The above code works perfectly fine on android and on IOS (before deployment). After deployment, when the page loads, initially it works as expected but suddenly the images start taking up the space of the text as well, moving text to the right (across the screen).

The image being in the first column, spanning to two rows should only take 30% of the space and rest should be occupied by the text as it appears before deployment.

Refer to the following images for further clarity:

[image: Once the page loads after deployment]

[image: Images in taking up the entire space]

Comment: Please help add the screenshot of the images start taking up the space of the text to your post.

Comment: Added. Please View.

Comment: First, you should use a `CollectionView` instead of a `ListView`. Second, assign the `Grid.Column="0"` to the Image. Last, if you're going to keep using the `ListView`, add `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` to the `ListView` in order to improve performance, you can read more here [ListView performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance).

Comment: @Aroosa Thanks for the update, can you try to add these properties to your `Image ` `MaximumWidthRequest="1"
    MaximumHeightRequest="1"  
    VerticalOptions="Fill"
    HorizontalOptions="Fill" ` to see if it works?

Comment: FWIW: @FabriBertani - *"Second, assign the Grid.Column="0" to the Image."* - That is optional; it defaults to 0; adding that has no effect. (Though it is good practice, for clarity; I do that whenever there are multiple columns.)

Comment: 1) Sounds like a Maui iOS bug. If no one suggests a work-around, create a public github repo with just enough code to run and see this bug. Create a new issue at `github maui issues`. 2) Re "deployment": Does it work on same device, in "debug" build? Is this when "published", or does any "release" build have the problem? If you send release build to ios simulator, does it work there?